# Query Limit from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database with about 500K row in it. I want get random row from row like 1 to 5000 and its limit result limit need like 100.

My current query is like below

```
'SELECT * FROM user where status='0' LIMIT 10,100'
```

what should I change or use for get limited random row, so I can get fast result without memory consume ?

Thanks

Comment: *from row like 1 to 5000* - what makes the rows 1 to 5000? what is the order here? You *do* know that a table is an unordered set of rows, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database table is an unordered set, so you'll have to provide some order to get 1 to 5000 rows (otherwise those will be any 1 to 5000 rows), may be based on userid.

Once you have that, you can limit the rows in subquery and sort by `rand()` and get first 100 like this:

```
select *
from (select
        *
    from user
        where status = 0
    order by /* set of columns, may be user_id*/
    limit 1, 5000
) t order by rand() limit 100;
```

Comment: T is an alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you any 100 random rows from your 5000k rows

```
select * from user where status='0' order by rand() limit 100
```

Comment: this will be very slow since rand() does not use index.

Comment: @abeyaz : Yes, as compared with the@GurV's query, this query is slow.